# Git branching not pushing to staging

Tags: git

So, when I run

```
git checkout staging
```

make some changes

```
git commit -a -m "*changes here*"
git push
git checkout master
git push staging master
```

I get back 
    "Everything up-to-date"

But everything isn't up to date, so, what am I doin' wrong?

Comment: I think you need to do a merge.

Comment: But that kinda defeats the purpose of Staging. Is there anyway of pushing it to staging without merging it with master?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you checked out the staging branch you then committed on top of that "Position", you could see what you are doing with something like

```
git diff staging master
```

maybe what you would do is to merge changes of staging branch on top of master, that is done merging this way:

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff staging #this creates a new commit even if a fast forward would be possible
```

then when you push to staging remote (I presume that it is a remote name, you could confirm with git remote -v ) you will end up updating the remote master with your mods.

Comment: Ah okay, is there anyway of pushing it to staging without merging it with master?

Comment: @Apane101 yes you do something like `git push staging staging:master`